# Passwordless SSH login

Tags: macos, ssh, centos

I want to login my server without the password, I have succeeded on the server localhost, but I failed when I try to login from my mac pro.

**First, I test on my server.**

1. Step 1: generate the Key
   [image]
2. Step 2: cat to the authorized_keys, and Try Passwordless SSH login localhost, there is no problem.
   [image]

**So, I try this on my mac pro**

3. Step 3: generate the key
   [image]
4. Step 4: copy the public key to my sever, and cat to the authorized_keys
   [image]
5. Step 5: try login to my sever on my mac pro, still need the password
   [image]
6. Step 6: I google the "Passwordless SSH login", and find on the [SSH](http://www.softpanorama.org/Net/Application_layer/SSH/passwordless_ssh_login.shtml) said that The file named authorized_keys should have permissions 600 & ~/.ssh directory should generally have permission 700. So I do the following step
   [image]
7. Step 7: **Still need the password**
   [image]

**Can someone help this problem? My mac is OS X 10.11, My server is CentOS 7.0 64bit**

---

Update:

1. The config is the authorized_keys
   [image]

Comment: Look into ssh config if `authorized_keys` is used and not `authorized_keys2`

Comment: I check the config, the authorized_keys is used

Comment: What is the filename containing your key on your client computer? If it is not  `id_dsa` (the default), then you need to issue your ssh with option `-i <key_filename>` (or configure it in `~/.ssh/config`).

Comment: Ah, the private key your are using is named not usable I think. Rename to id_dsa/rsa/ etc instead of specific name you use now or use the ssh command line tool to indicate which key you want to use to connect

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! The problem is caused by the filename~

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen -- you should move your answer to an answer so that the OP can select it as accepted.  I was quite confident that your answer wasn't right, but I was wrong .. and learned something!

Comment: Ok so is the answer is to rename the files. Please post the answer.

Comment: This answer may help: https://askubuntu.com/a/999306/398861

Comment: Even though this particular problem had a different solution - i ventured upon this trying to setup a passwordless DSA key on my MAC high sierra 10.13.   the solution was to create a passwordless "RSA" key as DSA is deprecated. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48794

Answer (score 1):

You process seems fine, but for MAC you seem to be missing one key step;

```
sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on
```

you need to configure MAC to accept remote logins through setremotelogin as above.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that RHEL 7 and SELinux were the root cause, even after tweaking every variable in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config and making more keys than a locksmith.  Login as root, and run this:

```
    setsebool -P use_nfs_home_dirs 1
```

You still have to create a key, share it with the other host login.  My issue was that we were using NFS based "home" directories, so SELinux wasn't allowing access without this explicit flag.

Let me know if your problem goes away.